# Gitlab runner does not always update environment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab job that does not seem to update the repository before being run. Sometimes it leaves some files in their old states and run the script... Any idea ?

For instance when I have a

```
packagePython:
  stage: package
  script: 
    - .\scripts\PackagePython.ps1
  tags: 
   - myServer
  cache:
    paths:
      - .\python\cache\
  only:
    changes:
      - python/**/*
```

Comment: Same, I'm running locally the runner for testing and Makefile is not updated. I've tried removing 'builds' and 'cache' dirs before running it but doesn't update Makefile.

Running it this way: `gitlab-runner exec shell my-job-name`

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to understand what was happening :
I realised that the **gitlab-runner did not use exactly the same path for each run** on my server, and my script assumed that it did... So I ended up pointing on a build made on the wrong path.

I guess if you think that it is not updating the repository (like I did) make sure you are not referencing hardcoded path/package in your scripts that could refer to previous versions !